# Background image not getting applied to ngx-file-drop component

Tags: html, css, angular

I have implemented the `ngx-file-drop` component in angular 7 application which allows drag and dropping files to upload. I need to change the background of the content area where while are dropped with an image. I have tried to `css` and also assign the `contentClassName` property like

`contentClassName = "upload-background-image"`

```
.upload-background-image {
     background-image: "./images/spritemap.png"
```

Its not applying background image. How do I it. Here is the [stackblitx](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1naelx)

html

```
<div class="center" class="file-upload-wrapper">
    <ngx-file-drop 
           dropZoneLabel="Drop files here"
           multiple="true" 
          (onFileDrop)="dropped($event)" 
          (onFileOver)="fileOver($event)" 
          (onFileLeave)="fileLeave($event)">
        <ng-template ngx-file-drop-content-tmp let-openFileSelector="openFileSelector">
          Optional custom content that replaces the the entire default content.
          <button type="button" (click)="openFileSelector()">Browse Files</button>


        </ng-template>
    </ngx-file-drop>
     <div class="upload-table">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="upload-name-style">
                <tr *ngFor="let item of files; let i=index">
                    <td><strong>{{ item.relativePath }}</strong></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I try to apply the following css it still doesnt apply

```
.ngx-file-drop__drop-zone {
     margin: 20px;
     height: 250px;
        background: #333;
        color: #fff;
        border: 5px dashed rgb(235, 79, 79);
        border-radius: 5px;
        font-size: 20px;


    }
```

Screenshot of how the html element looks like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information on your main post, where is the css class written in for exemple.

If your write your custom CSS inside the component style file, then it will not work, because ngx-file-drop will use his own component .css. To make it work, you need to put your custom css inside a general css file (like the global `style.css`)

Anyway, here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ha8hkm) with a background color, just inspire yourself from this.

Answer (score 0):

Add your css to global file **style.css**

This is the structure like this

```
"styles": [

  ],
```

you need to add this line under `"style":[],`

```
"src/styles.css"
```

If you want to add more styling then add your css class into **styles.css**

your souce code on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tdqsrx?file=src%2Fstyles.css)

Answer (score 0):

The class must be declared in global styles.

`dropZoneClassName="drop-zone"` translates to `class="drop-zone"` (not component based style), so the class must be declared in either the global style sheet or in the app.component.scss